# Semantic media wiki

Tags: media, semantics, semantic-mediawiki

What is the scripting language used by SEMANTIC MEDIA WIKI?

Answer (score 4):

PHP.  Same as regular mediawiki.

Answer (score 0):

Php is the scripting language.
sematic media wiki also uses wiki pipe language for editing.